# How to keep always keep a div at the bottom of another div

Tags: html, css

At current, i have some thumbnails that display information about them on hover over. The information is contained within a figcaption, then is made up of a title div, maincaption p, and footer p.

As each of the maincontent p sections vary in size, i'd like to know if its possible to keep the footer p at the bottom of the figcaption across all thumbnails to ensure they look even with each other.

At current, i have multiple id's for each footer div to manually line them all up due to maincontent p being a variety of sizes.

Any help would be appriciated!

One figcaption section example:

```
<figcaption class="caption">
<div class="captiontitle">Tracking Reel</div>
<p class="maincaption">Demonstrates different uses of image/motion tracking, including wire removal image replacement and rotoscoping. Attention to detail is key in this technique, a good eye essential.</p>
<p class="captionFooter">Adobe After Effects and Mocha were used.</p>
</figcaption>
```

One div CSS example:

```
.captionFooter
{
padding-top: 25px;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

My understanding is that, i'd like to be able to apply a style to `.captionFooter` that will apply to all the thumnails and keep it at the bottom, instead of pushing against `.maincaption` to keep it inline.

Comment: hm... {display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;} ?

Comment: As it currently looks, the `captionFooter` will always be at the bottom, because it is a paragraph, and *Browsers automatically add an empty line before and after a paragraph.*
If I am missing something, please try posting a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep a div at the bottom of div2, do this:

```
div{
  position: relative;
}

div2{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KFuuL/1/

Comment: -1: bad practice. What if you have tens of divs? How can you handle them with `relative`

Comment: I think he was using `div` as an example, and as i'm using classes for my elements, it should work perfectly

Comment: @CanGeliş Look at the answer carefully before you downvote dude. As Matt said that was an example. There is obviously no dom object called 'div2' and if you had bothered to look at the fiddle before downvoting you'd see that I have used ids in there.

Comment: @MattMeadows Hope this helped. You can accept it as the answer if it did :)

Comment: Spot on sir!
Thankyou very much :)